# Building a boolean logic parser in Scala with PackratParser

Tags: scala, parsing, packrat-parsing

I am trying to build a Boolean logic parser e.g. `A == B AND C == D` to output something like `And(Equals(A,B), Equals(C,D))`

My parser has the following definitions:

```
def program: Parser[Operator] = {
    phrase(operator)
}
def operator: PackratParser[Operator] = {
    leaf | node
}
def node: PackratParser[Operator] = {
    and | or 
}
def leaf: PackratParser[Operator] = {
    equal | greater | less
}
def and: PackratParser[Operator] = {
    (operator ~ ANDT() ~ operator) ^^ {
      case left ~ _ ~ right => And(left, right)}
}
```

I would expect the parser to map to `program -> operator -> node -> and -> operator (left) -> leaf -> equal -> operator (right) -> leaf -> equal`. This doesn't work.
However if in the above code I do the changes

```
def operatorWithParens: PackratParser[Operator] = {
    lparen ~> (operator | operatorWithParens) <~ rparen
}
```

and change `and` to be

```
def and: PackratParser[Operator] = {
    (operatorWithParens ~ ANDT() ~ operatorWithParens) ^^ {
      case left ~ _ ~ right => And(left, right)}
}
```

Parsing `(A == B) AND (C == D)` succeeds.

I can not wrap my head around why the former doesn't work while the later does.
How should I change my code to be able to parse `A == B AND C == D`?

EDIT:
Following @Andrey Tyukin advice I've modified the gramma to account for precedence

```
def program: Parser[Operator] = positioned {
    phrase(expr)
}
def expr: PackratParser[Operator] = positioned {
    (expr ~ ORT() ~ expr1) ^^ {
      case left ~ _ ~ right => Or(left, right)} | expr1
}
def expr1: PackratParser[Operator] = positioned {
    (expr1 ~ ANDT() ~ expr2) ^^ {
      case left ~ _ ~ right => And(left, right)} | expr2
}
def expr2: PackratParser[Operator] = positioned {
    (NOTT() ~ expr2) ^^ {case _ ~ opr => Not(opr)} | expr3
}
def expr3: PackratParser[Operator] = {
    lparen ~> (expr) <~ rparen | leaf
}
```

And although `PackratParser` supports left-recursive grammar, I run into an infinite loop that never leaves `expr`

Comment: What is `phrase`? What is `or`? It's somehow incomplete. Would it maybe be possible to provide the complete parser, with all the imports, ideally as an ammonite script with all dependencies?

Comment: Does it by any chance generate `Equals(And(Equals(A, B), C),D)`?  In other words it is parsed as `((A == B) AND C) == D`? Because without operator precedence that is what you would expect. We parse `A*B/C*D` differently from `A*B + C*D` because `+` has lower precedence than `*` but `/` has the same precedence as `*`. Operator precedence has to be expressed in the grammar.

Comment: When asking questions about parser combinators, you should specify which library is being used. Based on the presence of `^^` I would guess scala-parser-combinators? That is very slow and buggy and there are much better alternatives available (e. g. cats-parse).

Comment: @MatthiasBerndt Yes it is using scala-parser-combinators. The clue is the `packrat-parsing` tag and the word `PackratParser` in the title and in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a path from `operator` to a shorter `operator`:

```
operator -> node -> and -> (operator ~ somethingElse)
```

You seem to be assuming that the shorter `operator (left)` will somehow reduce to `leaf`, whereas the outermost `operator` would skip the `leaf` and pick the `node`, for whatever reason. What it does instead is just chocking on the first `leaf` it encounters.

You could try to move the `node` before the `leaf`, so that the whole `operator` doesn't choke on the first `A` when seeing sth. like `A == B AND ...`.

Otherwise, I'd suggest to refactor it into

- disjunctions
- of conjunctions
- of atomic formulas

where atomic formulas are either

- comparisons or
- indivisible parenthesized top-level elements (i.e. parenthesized
  disjunctions, in this case).

Expect to use quite a few `repSep`s.

Comment: I think moving `node` before `leaf` just makes it right associative rather than left associative so it still wouldn't parse correctly. It needs to implement operator precedence in order to parse the way that is wanted.

Comment: `just makes it right associative rather than left associative so it still wouldn't parse correctly` - I think you're right. It wouldn't parse correctly. But I somehow have the vague suspicion that it might actually parse as *something* instead of running into first leaf and giving up. Maybe it would even accept "the right language", even though it would generate a gibberish data structure out of it.

Comment: Either way the solution is definitely to model operator precedence in the grammar, but I don't know Packrat well enough to show how :)

Comment: > What it does instead is just chocking on the first leaf it encounters.

I was under the impression it will try all possible options till it finds one that matches the input string. Hence the idea of choking on the 1st wrong one seems weird as long as a valid path exists.

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie *"I was under the impression it will try all possible options till it finds one that matches the input string"* - you're correct, and that's exactly the problem: it find one that matches, it "eats" a part of the input, but then it finds that it can no longer "eat" whatever is coming after that, so it stops. Unlike your average LR-parser generated by yacc, it will not attempt to regurgitate the already consumed sub-`operator` and to ruminate and chew and eat it again. It's not a ruminant animal, it doesn't have this kind of backtracking behavior.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin does this mean that there must be only one unambiguous way to parse the input in order for this to work?

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie That's just a generally desirable property of a grammar: you really don't *ever* want to accept any inputs that could be parsed into more than one abstract syntax tree. Whether this property is automatically guaranteed by the flavor of parser you're currently using: not sure, would have to investigate and refresh some theory.